# Safe (format independent) way to .slice() time substring out of ISOString

Tags: javascript, date

Is it safe to use slice like this on ISOString to extract time from it?

```js
new Date().toISOString().slice(11, -8); //08:01
```

Comment: Why would that not be safe? You mean if they some day decided to change the output?

Comment: Probably safe but I'd probably use `.slice(11, 16);`.

Comment: @mplungjan yes.

Comment: FWIW, even if it's a bit more code, I'd always use `getUTCHours` and `getUTCMinutes` to build a custom string instead of this…

Answer (score 1):

> The `toISOString()` method returns a string in simplified extended ISO format (ISO 8601), which is always **24 or 27** characters long (`YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ` or `±YYYYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`, respectively).
>   <sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString</sub>

So, no, that particular code is not safe. You'd need to use negative offsets for both to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

I would think there are safer options since

> The [toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) method returns a string in simplified extended ISO format (ISO 8601), which is always 24 or 27 characters long
>   `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ` or
>   `±YYYYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`,
>   respectively). The timezone is always zero UTC offset, as denoted by the suffix "Z".

Whereas [toUTCString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString) has only one type of output according to MDN. This may not be correct as seen in the [ecma262](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date.prototype.toutcstring) where there may be negative dates - the code below should still work

```js
const t1 = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[1].slice(0, -8); 
const t2 = new Date().toUTCString().split(" ")[4].slice(0, -3); // safer 
const t3 = new Date().toLocaleTimeString("en-GB").slice(0, -3)  // if you want user's time

console.log(t1,t2,t3)

// or as deceze suggested in his comment
const pad = num => ("0"+num).slice(-2);

const d = new Date();
const t4 = `${pad(d.getUTCHours())}:${pad(d.getUTCMinutes())}`;
console.log(t4)
```

Comment: *toUTCString* can also have years greater than 4 digits and also has negative years with a sign, e.g. Mon, 31 Jan -270000 14:00:00 GMT is a valid timestamp.

Comment: @RobG That is not in MDN - I think that is a grave omission

Comment: I see in the [specs](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date.prototype.toutcstring) that my `.toUTCString().split(" ")[4].slice(0, -3)` would work regardless

Comment: MDN is a great resource, but it's maintained by anyone who cares to create a login so not always accurate. I always take it with a grain of salt. :-) The specification section was good as it had the history of features over various editions of ECMA-262, but that seems to have been abandoned to only reference the most recent entry. :-(

Comment: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date.prototype.toutcstring has the negative value present

Answer (score 1):

If you need it to work regardless of time-substring position within output string, you may stick to `:` delimiter, using RegExp, though, it probably may be somewhat slower compared to `slice()` or `split()`:

```js
const [time] = new Date().toISOString().match(/\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}/g)

console.log(time)
```

Comment: Also a better idea

Comment: This returns an array, not a string. The *g* flag is redundant. `.slice(-13,-8)` is less to type. ;-)

Comment: `const [time] = new Date().toISOString().match(/\d{1,2}:\d{2}/)` works when console.loggging it and is in principle safer than the slice

Comment: @mplungjan : to those, who's lazy to use destructuring of array, returned by `match()`, there's an easy workaround - `[0]` appended to `match(...`

Comment: Actually no need it seems  - I would normally agree but the statement I pasted does not result in an array that I can see - if it does, the toString  returns the [0]